# TSAlertView crashes when the presenting view controller is replaced

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, exc-bad-access, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using the excellent [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView) project to create popup alerts with enlarged fonts for people with visual impairments. Unfortunately I've encountered a problem that has been puzzling me for a couple of days.

I'm using a `TSAlertView` as a validator popup when a user is about to move to a new page in the app to confirm the content of the current page. I.e., the user presses a button to move to a new page in the app, the `TSAlertView` popups on the screen and if the user presses the Yes button, the current `UIViewController` is replaced with a different `UIViewController` using a custom segue. The app randomly crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and my educated guess is that it crashes when the current `UIViewController` is deallocated before the `TSAlertView` has completed its dismiss animation.

An obvious workaround is to increase the duration of the animation between the current `UIViewController` and the new one, but that would simply rely on good timing, which is recipe for disaster. Is there an easy way to prevent the presenting `UIViewController` from being deallocated till the `TSAlertView` is deallocated? The main project uses ARC while `TSAlertView` is non-ARC.

EDIT: rubber-ducking in action. I added the following 2 lines in the `-(void) show` method:

```
_presentingViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
[_presentingViewController retain];
```

And a corresponding `release` in the `-(void) dealloc`. Everything seems to work properly now. Am I creating a circular retain chain? Is there a better answer?

Comment: You should use Instruments's Zombies template to find exactly what's causing the crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Hosey is right - you *should* use Zombies to find exactly what's causing the crash.

However, my gut tells me (after looking at TSAlertView.h), that you're setting your view controller as the delegate when you show the alert view. You're guess seems likely, your view controller is being deallocated, and the alert view is attempting to talk to a dangling pointer.

Bad new is, if your controller has retained the AlertView, you have *likely* caused a retain loop with your fix. Even if you haven't, the change is so terribly likely *to* cause a retain loop, I wouldn't make it.

Good news is, you can still apply pre-ARC best practices, and nil your delegates. Under ARC, dealloc is still a valid method that is called when your object is deallocated - you just don't call super. This gives you a chance to cleanup when your object reaches the end of it's life. If you keep a reference to the alert view after you display it, then you should be able to do something like like the following to cleanup the dangling pointer:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.alertView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, and sorry for not accepting the answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this error **[TSAlertView onKeyboardWillShow:]: message sent to deallocated instance** while trying to open TSAlert simultaneously.
My Solution is below:

Try do 2 steps :

1. Add  -fno-objc-arc flag for TSAlertView class. For instructions go to: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)
2. Add line [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];  into **onKeyboardWillHide:** method of TSAlertView class under **animations: ^** block.

Hope it helps, It worked for me.